# Can't get many-to-many relation but attach/detach works correctly in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Full error is:

```
1066 Not unique table/alias: 
SQL: select `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.*,
    `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_id` as `pivot_salons_services_id`,
    `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_sex_id` as `pivot_salons_services_sex_id`
from `salons_services_salons_services_sex`
    inner join `salons_services_salons_services_sex` on `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`id` = `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_sex_id`
where `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_id` = 92
```

Model:

```
class SalonService extends Model
{

    public function sex() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\SalonServiceSex',
            'salons_services_salons_services_sex',
            'salons_services_id',
            'salons_services_sex_id')
        ;
    }
}
```

Trying to get related records with $service->sex is leading to error, but attach() or detach() works correctly so I can link models with this methods.

**EDIT:**
Updated generated query to

```
select `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.*,
  `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_id` as `pivot_salons_services_id`,
  `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_sex_id` as `pivot_salons_services_sex_id`
  from `salons_services_salons_services_sex`
    inner join `salons_services_sex` as s1
      on s1.`id` = `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_sex_id`
  where `salons_services_salons_services_sex`.`salons_services_id` = 93
```

and it works fine

Getting the related records:

```
$service->sex;
```

Tables:

```
salons_services:
id
name
time

salons_services_salons_services_sex:
salons_services_id
salons_services_sex_id

salons_services_sex:
id
name
```

Comment: Can you add code how you're getting the related records and which table corresponds to which model.

Comment: Added code and tables

Comment: Have you added to each model what the correct table name is?

Comment: yes, all names are correct

Comment: strange. I did a few things and bug  disappeared. I'll try to answer the question if I'll understand what exactly caused the bug.